# Listing files with grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, ls

I have a directory that contains the following files:

```
file1a file1ab file12A2 file1Ab file1ab
```

I want to list all files that start with `file1` and followed by two letter at most!

The solution I have proposed is as follows:

```
ls | grep -i file1 [az] {2}
```

But it does not work!

I want to know why? and how to list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need piping, `grep` or `ls`. Just use shell globbing.

In `bash`, using `extglob` pattern (should be enabled by default in interactive sessions, if not do `shopt -s extglob` to set it first):

```
file1@(|?|??)
```

`?` matched any single character, `@(||)` selects any of the patterns separated by `|`.

If you only meant to match any characters between `a-z` and `A-Z`, use use character class `[:alpha:]` which denotes all alphabetic characters in the current locale:

```
file1@(|[[:alpha:]]|[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]])
```

**Example:**

```
$ ls -1
file1
file112
file11a
file12A2
file1a
file1ab
file1Ab
file1as
file2
fileadb

$ ls -1 file1@(|[[:alpha:]]|[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]))
file1
file1a
file1ab
file1Ab
file1as
```

---

`zsh` supports this natively:

```
file1(|[[:alpha:]]|[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]])
```

---

**I am answering this portion very reluctantly, upon request from OP.**

**Any future reader, Don't parse `ls`, use globbing.**

Using `ls` and `grep`:

```
ls | grep -E '^file1[[:alpha:]]{,2}$'
```

**Example:**

```
% ls | grep -E '^file1[[:alpha:]]{,2}$'
file1
file1a
file1ab
file1Ab
file1as
```

Comment: Thank you !  but the problem is that we have not yet studied all that! is it possible to do this task using `ls` and `grep` and piping ?

Comment: @MahmoudAssyass Check my edits but you absolutely should (read must) use shell globbing..

Comment: I'm very sorry to disturb you! I am aware that stupid questions annoy you! Thank you for bearing with me

Comment: @MahmoudAssyass Come on..nobody is disturbing anybody..i am very happy to help you..just a caveat that you should start using globbing for these kind of tasks rather than ugly `ls | grep ..` :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and also for your quick response. It is definitely appreciated.

Comment: But there still one little problem with your answer ! you forgot to list those who are followed by capitalized letters

Comment: @MahmoudAssyass Check my edits..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31795/discussion-between-mahmoud-assyass-and-heemayl).

Comment: @MahmoudAssyass Chat isn't working..have you checked my latest edit?

Comment: I just tried this with bash version 4.1.2 (Redhat system) and it did not work. What version of bash is required? Or is this an Ubuntu add-on?

Comment: @MarkGerolimatos Set the shell option `extglob` first..`shopt -s extglob`

Comment: but there still one more little problem, it would be better if you added it for future readers, you must add the option `-w` for `grep`, because if you dont it will give you a list of all files that contain `file1`

Comment: @MahmoudAssyass No it should not.. Can you give an example? Also file names with `file1` at start with a maximum of 2 letters..isn't what you need?

Answer (score 3):

Whats about find?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '\./file1[a-z]{,2}.*'
```

Comment: I know very well that we can solve this problem thanks to other methods, but is it possible to do that just by using `grep` and `ls` and piping !

Comment: I don't understand why you are focused on `grep` and `ls`, except as an exercise. `Find` is the preferred way to do such complicated tasks, as it can be done in a single command and not require a shell master. Furthermore, it can be MUCH more efficient on large directories, as it need not output non-matching strings. A minor efficiency to be sure, but an efficiency nevertheless. Although, I must admit that the line above *does* look quite intimidating: `find` is not known for ease of use :-)

Answer (score 3):

`find` with `-regex` flag is more appropriate for this sort of job, especially since it's a general rule that [output of ls should never be parsed](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).

However, you've stated that you are looking for files only in one directory ( not descending into subdirectories ), and that you'd specifically want `ls` and `grep`. The solution is

```
\ls | grep -E 'file1[a-z]{2,}'
```

Considering also that you are searching in the current directory, but avoiding parsing `ls`, here's another solution

```
 for file in * ; do echo "$file" | grep -E 'file1[a-z]{2,}' ;done                                        
./file1ab
./file1abc
```

In my current directory, I have two files, `file1ab` and `file1abc`. In both cases, the result is the following:

```
xieerqi:$ for file in * ; do echo "$file" | grep -E 'file1[a-z]{2,}' ;done                                        
./file1ab
./file1abc

xieerqi:$ \ls | grep -E 'file1[a-z]{2,}'                                                                            
file1ab
file1abc
```